# fingerprintjs not loading in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to load [fingerprintjs](https://github.com/fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs) in my chrome extension and for some reason it is not loading.
The documentation says to use this approach, which works fine in standalone web sites, just not in chrome extensions

```
<script>
    function initFingerprintJS() {
      FingerprintJS.load().then(fp => {
        // The FingerprintJS agent is ready.
        // Get a visitor identifier when you'd like to.
        fp.get().then(result => {
          // This is the visitor identifier:
          const visitorId = result.visitorId;
          console.log("visitorId", visitorId);
        });
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script async src="fp.min.js" onload="initFingerprintJS();"></script>
```

For chrome extension I added created a JS file `initFingerprint.js` that holds the init code like so:

```
var visitorId = null; //will hold the actual fingerprint
function initFingerprintJS() {
    console.log("inside initFingerprintJS");
    FingerprintJS.load().then(fp => {
        console.log("loaded initFingerprintJS");
        fp.get().then(result => {
            console.log("initFingerprintJS got result", result)
            visitorId = result.visitorId; // This is the visitor identifier
            console.log("visitorId", visitorId);
        });
    });
}
initFingerprintJS();
```

In background.html, I added this:

```
<script async src="fp.min.js"></script>
<script async src="initFingerprint.js"></script>
```

I have tried with `async` in there and not in there, but still no luck. This line will print, but none of the other lines below it.

```
inside initFingerprintJS
```

What am I doing wrong? I appreciate any help. thank you

Comment: I have the same issue, the `FingerprintJS.load()` is returning an empty promise.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<script>` tag for `fp.min.js` from the html and create the script element yourself in initFingerprint.js so you can use the `onload` event directly:

```js
loadScript('fp.min.js').then(initFingerprintJS);

function loadScript(url) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const el = document.createElement('script');
    el.onload = resolve;
    el.onerror = reject;
    el.src = url;
    document.documentElement.appendChild(el);
  });
}

async function initFingerprintJS() {
  visitorId = await (await FingerprintJS.load()).get();
  console.log('visitorId', visitorId);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried what you suggested. In background.html I loaded the file with the script above `initFingerprint.js`. I tried loading with `async` flag and without. Basically the code gets stuck at this line `await (await FingerprintJS.load()).get();` It is not able to clear the `load` function. Any ideas?

Comment: No ideas. Use non-minified fp.js and debug the code in devtools debugger by stepping inside fingerprint functions.

Comment: Also, I noticed that the script element that gets created looks like this? `<script src="fp.min.js"></script>` I would have thought there would be others attributes to this element like onload and such?

Comment: 1. One idea: you might have used the wrong distribution of fp.js, there are several, so in some you may need to access `exports` and such. Use devtools debugger to ascertain the returned object. 2. DOM events aren't mapped to attributes. 3. No need for `async` attribute.

Comment: I downloaded from http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs@3/dist/fp.min.js As I mentioned it works in a website just fine, just not in chrome extension. I could not find an unminified version and it is so hard to debug this darn thing given the minification transformation applied. I need to see if there is a way I can build it from source.

Comment: Download the unminified one from the [parent directory on CDN](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@fingerprintjs/fingerprintjs@3/dist/).